# Saving URL params in a session (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, session, parameters

I'm trying to save the url params from ever page, into a session, so if someone fills out a form after navigating away from their landing page it keeps the campaign id. I've managed to make it work page by page, so if they land on the form with params it keeps it, but if they navigate away obviously it doesn't. I currently have:

Controller:

```
def campaign
  if params[:campaign]!= nil
    session[:campaign] = params[:campaign]
  end
end

def post

  rif = Registerinterest.find(:all, :conditions => ["reference = ?", session[:campaign]])

  if rif.count == 0
    post["Campaign_ID"] = "701D00000001111"
  else
    post["Campaign_ID"] = rif.first.campaign_id
  end
end
```

It worked when i used params, but not session, so i'm assuming i'm not saving it properly?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I put this in my application layout:

```
- if params[:campaign] != nil || params[:campaign] != ""
  - session[:campaign] == params[:campaign]
```

and then that made the controller work properly:

```
def post

  rif = Registerinterest.find(:all, :conditions => ["reference = ?", session[:campaign]])

  if rif.count == 0
    post["Campaign_ID"] = "701D00000001111"
  else
    post["Campaign_ID"] = rif.first.campaign_id
  end
end
```

Comment: I think what @awenkhh suggested is more the Rails way, but it's your choice.

Answer (score 9):

You could add a before filter in controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter persist_campaign_session

  def persist_campaign_session
    session[:campaign] ||= params[:campaign]
  end
end
```

If `session[:campaign]` is set it will be used, otherwise `params[:campaign]`will be used. You should implement 
the reset of `session[:campaign]` at a good place.

Comment: I need it to set params[:campaign] as session[:campaign] so it can be used anywhere

Comment: the ApplicationController is called with each request because all controllers inherit from it. What you did below is logic which is not supposed to be placed in a view file. Try it like I suggested and you are on the Rails track ;-)